# How to add option in Python code?

Tags: python

I have a Python script a.py and b.py, I'd like to call the main function of b.py and pass arguments from a.py. How to add option in a.py from inside the code and pass it to the main of b.py ?. I tried adding the dictionary my additional option but for some unknown reason the b.py doesn't get the right value. The add_option only works for command line option.

I've imported b inside a.py, I'm trying to pass readOnly value to main in b.py. Basically I don't want to pass readOnly from a.py as command line but pass the readOnly through the code inside a.py.

```
a.py

import b

def main()
    usage = "usage: %prog [options]"
    parser = OptionParser(usage)
    (options, _ ) = parser.parse_args()
    varsOptions = vars(options)
    varsOptions['readOnly'] = True
    b.main(varsOptions)


b.py

def main(argv):
    usage = "usage: %prog [options]"
    parser = OptionParser(usage)
    parser.add_option("-r", action="store_true", dest="readOnly")
    (options, _ ) = parser.parse_args()
    varsOptions = vars(options)
    print(varsOptions)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Why this code doesn't work ?.

TIA,

John

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is `b` to be imported, or run as a separate process?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to execute a python script file with an argument from inside another python script file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230725/how-to-execute-a-python-script-file-with-an-argument-from-inside-another-python)

Comment: It's fine if you want to close it but it doesn't answer my question why my code snippet doesn't work.

Comment: What does `b.main` look like?

Comment: Update the question with b.py snippet. The print of varsOptions doesn't show the value True from readOnly.

Comment: "This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. "

Really ?. Janne got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because `b.main` does not use the `argv` parameter.

You could pass `argv` to `parse_args` as a parameter, but it should be a list of strings, not a dictionary.

Try this in `a`:

```
b.main(["-r"])
```

Answer (score 2):

You should see examples from official doc : http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html for argparse

For an older python, see http://docs.python.org/dev/library/optparse.html

Comment: @YuvalAdam: No, argparse also works fine in Python 2.7, see http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html.

Comment: argparse is available for many versions of python: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse

Comment: @sputnick: It is not clear to me that the OP wants to run `b.py` in a separate process, perhaps `import` will be enough..

Answer (score 0):

this is not really a good idea.

but if you need to do it you can do it with the os run commands

os.system('script.py "options" ')

you should read the following stack overflow

[how to execute a python script file with an argument from inside another python script file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230725/how-to-execute-a-python-script-file-with-an-argument-from-inside-another-python)

Comment: Ah, thanks for the question pointer, voting to close this one as a dupe of that one!

Comment: Not sure is it because Python can't do this easily like my code excerpt ?.

Comment: This is not a dup....look at the comment from the original poster on that thread, he hasn't been able to make it to work.