# How can I call a python file present in another directory through python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

So I made an HWID Spoofer with python!
Here's an example:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'C:/Program Files/changer.bat')
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'C:/Program Files/mac_changer.py')
```

My main python program is in desktop. Now, I need to call the bat file and other necessary python files from a different directory. How do I do that??

I have tried os.system - tho it works only for the current directory only
so does the exec command!

Please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch a file from a local url with Python requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123929/fetch-a-file-from-a-local-url-with-python-requests)

Comment: Does this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230725/how-to-execute-a-python-script-file-with-an-argument-from-inside-another-python) answer your question?

Comment: @Daniil Thanks for the quick reply unfortuantely no :-(

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh Thank for the real quick reply, I believe that answered my question, I'll give it a try now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `os.chdir(path)` before youre running `os.system` os.chdir changes the working directory.

example:

```py
os.chdir("C:/Program Files/");
os.system("changer.bat");
```

Comment: I'm gonna give that a quick try and tell you :-)